# How to find the model binding errors at submit on JSP

Tags: jquery, jsp, spring-mvc

I have a JSP screen as part of a project. Everything worked fine, submits, etc. A certain requirement is to come back to any part of my project based on what was saved. I now have the problem that when I submit it doesn't reach my controller. It just goes to the default technical error page the site has set up. No errors in my chrome console, no erros on my application server console. This has happened before and it had to do with binding errors. So the inputs on the form binding back (In my previous example I tried to submit something back in an array that was on and index that didn't exist - luckily this one I could see).

Question: How can I see or get an idea which binding issues are causing that I don't even reach my handleSubmit on my controller? I can't put a breakpoint and debug, but I can't see anything obvious wrong. I put the form code and the submit method parameters below:

```
<form:form commandName="cardApplicationDto" method="post" action="" id="MainForm">
```

Button Click

`$('button[name=saveExit]').click(function() {
            console.log("Save Exit link");
            setPhoneNumbers();
            showBusyAndSubmit('saveExit', 'spinner', 'MainForm');
        });`

In my controller (But never reach this)

```
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String handleSubmit(HttpServletRequest aHttpServletRequest,
                @ModelAttribute(
                                CardApplicationWebConstants.SESSION_CARD_APPLICATION) CardApplicationDto aCardApplicationDto,
                Errors errors) throws Exception {
```

Comment: check your url mapping

Comment: If I come through my app in a normal way, the submit and save buttons work perfectly. If I come from a previously saved version it doesn't. The mapping is correct. So I suspect something in the data that binds on the form isn't right when I load it from a saved version. I need to know how to catch these errors. Or just debug so I can find the problem.